# Save image to local automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and html5. I'm doing my college project. I'm creating a web-based photo capturing system. Is it possible to automatically save the image to local storage. After user had hit on the capture button?

FYI,
when the user hit on capture button, it active this function

`function(){context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240)}`

Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman hard disk. Sorry, I'm blur. Because after converting the canvas to jpg. Instead of we RIGHT CLICK on the IMAGE and click save as. Can I make it automatically?

Comment: No, you don't have access to the file storage on the client's PC. (At least not with prior permission of the user)

Comment: @PatrickHofman But is there any solution to overcome this problem. Cause my purpose of doing this is to let another KIOSK device to access the image file that being captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) to generate an `<a>` link which would allow the user to download the image:

```
function(){
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    dl.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    dl.innerHTML = "Download Image!";
    dl.download = true; // Make sure the browser downloads the image
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // Needs to be added to the DOM to work
    dl.click(); // Trigger the click
}
```

This should then initiate the download of the image. This relies on browser support of the `download` attribute.

[<kbd>Example jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/yu9ky/)

Comment: @PatrickHofman The OP is calling `context.drawImage` which is a method on [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) which is gained by calling `canvas.getContext()`. So I assume they have a reference to `canvas` somewhere.