# Auto save image or by button

Tags: css

This code is for writing text on the image .. I had trouble saving the image, I cannot save it to the phone
I got a solution here and succeeded in saving the pictures to the phone ..
In answer number 1
[Save image to local automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950766/save-image-to-local-automatically)

but I couldn't use it for my code

```js
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("canvas").style.display = "block";
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 //demoo document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

 addTextToImage("https://l.top4top.io/p_1549mpaz31.png", x);
}
function addTextToImage(imagePath, text) {
    var circle_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = circle_canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Draw Image function
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imagePath;
    img.onload = function () {
        context.font = "40px Cairo";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        context.lineStyle = "#ffff00";
        context.fillText(text, 520, 790);
        
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:300,400,600,700,900');
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-family: 'Cairo';
  
}
```

```html
<canvas style="display:none" id="canvas" width="1080" height="1080"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="myText" value="write your name">
<button onclick="myFunction()">button</button> .. 
<p id="demoo"></p>
```

Comment: I am still waiting for help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a codepen for you. Please check and let me know if you have any more query. I just focused on how you can download image from canvas. I think that is your most concerned issue.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="write your name">
<button onclick="writeText()">Show Image</button>  
<button onclick="download()">Download Image</button>  
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
function writeText() {
    console.log("Hello")
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var name = document.getElementById("text").value;

    if(name.trim() == "" || name.trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Write something in the text box first");
            return;
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(name, 10, 50);
}

function download() {
    writeText()
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'text.png';
    link.href = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()
    link.click();
}
```

https://codepen.io/kousik-mandal/pen/RwWjmqM

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you from my heart ..
The problem is adding the image as a background 
The text appears on the image .. but I could not download the image on mobile
If you can review the above code until the idea becomes clear to you ..
I just want a button that saves the image + text

addTextToImage("https://l.top4top.io/p_1549mpaz31.png", x);

Thank you ,,